# Setting UserBaseDirectory for custom packages

Tags: packages, files-and-directories, system

Is there any reason to set `$UserBaseDirectory` to be anything other than the default?

On my mac its set as `~/Library/Mathematica`. It's been suggested that I should change this, and then add my own package directory to `~/Library/Mathematica/Applications` for my own written packages, but I cannot for the life of my figure out how to permanently set environment variables on OSX 10.8.

Additionally, I don't understand how why simply adding the path to my package directories hosted elsewhere to `$Path` via  `~/Library/Mathematica/Kernel/init.m` would be wrong for my own written packages?

Comment: I am inclined to say no (default `$UserBaseDirectory` is just fine) and yes (simply adding the package location to `$Path` should suffice).

Comment: Great, I've spent many a hour trying how to set a permanent environment variable on osx to a new $UserBaseDirectory with no luck.

Comment: Yes, with OS X it is a bit of a moving target... I've found [this](http://www.dowdandassociates.com/blog/content/howto-set-an-environment-variable-in-mac-os-x/) to be helpful.